# Como estilizar componentes aninhados com Shadow DOM?

Tags: css, dom

Possuo 2 componentes web aninhados que utilizam Shadow DOM. O primeiro, `my-component`, apenas renderiza o segundo componente:

```html
<my-another-component part="my-another-component" />
```

E o segundo, `my-another-component`, renderiza um elemento nativo:

```html
<div part="my-div"></div>
```

Como posso estilizar a `div` a partir de um componente que renderiza o `my-component`?

O resultado final desse último componente seria algo como:

```html
<style>/* ... */</style>

<my-component>
    #shadow-root
        <my-another-component part="my-another-component">
            #shadow-root
                <div part="my-div"></div>
        </my-another-component>
</my-component>
```

Tentei utilizar o pseudo-elemento `::part` aninhado, porém não funcionou:

```css
my-component::part(my-another-component)::part(my-div) {
    color: blue;
}
```

```js
customElements.define('my-component',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      let template = document.getElementById('my-component');

      this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        .appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
  }
);

customElements.define('my-another-component',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      let template = document.getElementById('my-another-component');

      this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        .appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<style>
  my-component::part(my-another-component) {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  my-component::part(my-another-component)::part(my-div) {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
<my-component></my-component>

<template id="my-component">
  <my-another-component part="my-another-component"></my-another-component>
</template>

<template id="my-another-component">
  <div part="my-div">Example</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Quem é vivo sempre aparece :D. Cara nesse caso vc tem que criar a tag <style> no escopo do script do web component imagino

Comment: @hugocsl opa, não estive usando muito SOpt, as vezes entro chat e no meta. Tu diz dentro do Shadow DOM do `my-another-component`? Teria uma maneira sem injetar código dentro do outro componente?

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui, olha como a tag style vai dentro do template do web componente com um innerHTML https://css-tricks.com/styling-a-web-component/#move-the-styles-inline-inside-the-web-component isso aqui tb deve te interessar https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/ fala sobre ::part e ::theme

Comment: @hugocsl o `exportparts` resolve a pergunta, apesar das limitações. Mas tem um erro no link, múltiplas exportações deve ser separadas por "," e não por " ". Você pode adicionar uma resposta com essa solução

Comment: Vou deixar para outro responder, pois eu estaria falando de algo que eu não domino rss. Na verdade só comentei aqui pq esses dia precisei dar uma olhada em web componentes e vi que os caras injetavam o css direto fazendo um innerHtml com a tag style. Mas que bom que ajudou ai